# Create instance of object with only string of class name.

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I'm new to scala and trying to figure things out as I go. I'm working with the Play 2.x framework and using Scala to build my app. I have a route defined

```
GET /:tableName   controllers.Application.getTable(tableName)
```

In the controller I would like to take the name of the table and use it as I would the class. For example in the db if have a table named People. I would like it to map to the Slick model for People that has the function getAll. I looked into typeof[t], but couldn't get it to work. below it is an example of what I would like to do.

```
def getTable(tableName: String) = Action {

    Ok(Json.toJson(typeOf[tableName].getAll))
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need a bit more than that, to get this accomplished ;) First of all, Slick requires a DB session, so that needs to be handled somewhere. Meaning a Slick Table `getAll` won't work by itself.

I would do something like this (sorry, typing this up without an IDE, so it may not compile):

```
case class Person(...)
object People extends Table[Person](PeopleDAO.table) {
  def * = ...
}

trait DAO[T] {
  val table: String
  def getAll: Seq[T]
}

object PeopleDAO extends DAO[Person] {
  override val table = "people"
  def getAll = {
    DB withSession { implicit session =>
      Query(People).list
    }
  }
}
object Controller {
  def getTable(tableName: String) = Action {
    val dao: DAO[_] = tableName.toLowerCase match {
      case PeopleDAO.table => PeopleDAO
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid table.")
    }
    Ok(Json.toJson(dao.getAll))
  }
}
```

Comment: I do have a model that looks similar to what you have above. The problems is that I have several models with .getAll defined. I'm hoping to pass in the name of the object using a string and call the .getAll for the appropriate method.

Comment: Can you generalize the `.getAll` to a trait like the `DAO` has?